# Why do I have to explicitly state Tuple2(a, b) to be able to use Map add in a foldLeft?

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

I wish to create a Map keyed by name containing the count of things with that name. I have a list of the things with name, which may contain more than one item with the same name. Coded like this I get an error "type mismatch; found : String required: (String, Int)":

```
//variation 0, produces error 
(Map[String, Int]() /: entries)((r, c) => { r + (c.name, if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1) })
```

This confuses me as I though (a, b) was a Tuple2 and therefore suitable for use with Map add. Either of the following variations works as expected:

```
//variation 1, works
(Map[String, Int]() /: entries)((r, c) => { r + Tuple2(c.name, if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1) })
//variation 2, works
(Map[String, Int]() /: entries)((r, c) => { 
    val e = (c.name, if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1) })
    r + e
```

I'm unclear on why there is a problem with my first version; can anyone advise. I am using Scala-IDE 2.0.0 beta 2 to edit the source; the error is from the Eclipse Problems window.

Comment: entries groupBy (_.name) mapValues (_.length)  // SO is eating my underscores

Comment: Depending on type and length of `entries`, this might perform _a lot_ worse.

Comment: I think it'll always be a constant factor slower. Which, depending on your domain could still be considered "a lot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a single tuple argument to a method used with operator notation, like your `+` method, you should use double parentheses:

```
(Map[String, Int]() /: entries)((r, c) => { r + ((c.name, r.get(c.name).map(_ + 1).getOrElse(1) )) })
```

I've also changed the computation of the `Int`, which looks funny in your example…

Comment: OK, so if I follow it thinks that `r + (a,b)` means "call the + method on r passing in `a,b`, thus `r + ((a,b))` means "call the plus method on r passing in `(a,b)` (eg Tuple2(a,b). Though mildly annoying day-to-day that does make sense; thank you.

EDIT: And thanks for the reminder of getOrElse; moving over from Java & I still tend to think ?: => if/else for cases where getOrElse makes more sense.

Comment: @S42 Yes, you got it. If you don't like the double parentheses, you can use [Alexey's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940822/why-do-i-have-to-explicitly-state-tuple2a-b-to-be-able-to-use-map-add-in-a-fol/5941166#5941166) to use the “arrow” `->` to create the tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Because `+` is used to concatenate strings stuff with strings. In this case, parenthesis are not being taken to mean a tuple, but to mean a parameter.

Scala has used `+` for other stuff, which resulted in all sorts of problems, just like the one you mention.

Replace `+` with `updated`, or use `->` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r + (c.name, if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1)
```

is parsed as

```
r.+(c.name, if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1)
```

So the compiler looks for a `+` method *with 2 arguments* on `Map` and doesn't find it. The form I prefer over double parentheses (as Jean-Philippe Pellet suggests) is

```
r + (c.name -> if (r.contains(c.name)) (c.name) + 1 else 1)
```

UPDATE:

if Pellet is correct, it's better to write

```
r + (c.name -> r.getOrElse(c.name, 0) + 1)
```

(and of course James Iry's solution expresses the same intent even better).

Comment: But `(c.name) + 1` is not an `Int`… I think the OP meant `r(c.name) + 1` instead. And then, the lookup is performed twice — once for `contains`, and once for `apply`.